# Cannot pair bluetooth Wacom Stylus to Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, bluetooth

(Disclaimer: I know this pen is meant for iPads etc. but I sort of want to hack it for windows 8 - I don't care about the pen part, we just wanted to have a go with the buttons).

We have a Wacom Intuos Creative Stylus which is bluetooth-based (has buttons on it) and is meant for use with iPads.

I was wondering if anyone knows how to get this (or other similar bluetooth devices) to pair with Windows 8 (I have a Windows 8 pro tablet/laptop).

Windows sees it as 'Stylus - Unknown' when I go to Devices and Printers -> Add a Device but when I try and connect I just get the error:

> That didn't work - Try again and make sure that your device is still discoverable

Which isn't really of much help.

I was assuming that it might just be able to pair with a 0000 passcode and then show up as a HID device that I could then go hacking around but no luck.

Does anyone have any idea what else I can try? Or any bluetooth testing software I could use to see what is going on and why it is failing etc?

Thanks for your time